# Unable to assign genesis balance in Ethereum private network

Tags: private-blockchain

Cant able to assign the balance through the custom genesis.json file.here is my screenshots.[image]

Comment: i had minned but still the balance is 0. so i moved to pre-allocation. Could u suggest what can i do to rectify this issue. @niksmac

Comment: Make sure concise is set to the correct address.

Comment: peers are connected, no issues in that......but node's local balance itself not displayed....is genesis file ignored..? after updating pre-allocation of ether balance..?

Comment: Did you reset your blockchain after modifying the genesis file?

Comment: how can i reset the genesis file without losing the created wallet..?

Comment: solved the issue...the mistake that i had made was i deleted the keystore too while re-initializing the .json file

Comment: Please post your own answer with details to help the next person who runs into the same problem.

Comment: after reinitializing genesis.json file i am able to get the balance but cant able get the peercount which is working fine earlier...could someone educate me what is happenoing....?

Comment: yes i had reset the blockchain and reinitialized genesis file...but if balance issue cleared then peercount suffers and vice versa

Comment: @Gowtham please move your explanation of the solution from the comments to an Answer and mark it complete. From what I understand you're facing a different issue now so please search/create a new Question for that.